# Reorganizing data

Tags: python, file

I have to input a text file that contains comma seperated and line seperated data in the following format:

```
A002,R051,02-00-00,05-21-11,00:00:00,REGULAR,003169391,001097585,05-21-11,04:00:00,REGULAR,003169415,001097588,05-21-11,08:00:00,REGULAR,003169431,001097607
```

Multiple sets of such data is present in the text file

I need to print all this in new lines with the condition:
1st 3 elements of every set followed by 5 parameters in a new line. So solution of the above set would be:

```
A002,R051,02-00-00,05-21-11,00:00:00,REGULAR,003169391,001097585
A002,R051,02-00-00,05-21-11,04:00:00,REGULAR,003169415,001097588
A002,R051,02-00-00,05-21-11,08:00:00,REGULAR,003169431,001097607
```

My function to achieve it is given below:

```
def fix_turnstile_data(filenames):    
    for name in filenames:
        f_in = open(name, 'r')
        reader_in = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter = ',')
        f_out = open('updated_' + name, 'w')
        writer_out = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter = ',')

        array=[]
        for line in reader_in:
            i = 0
            j = -1 
            while i < len(line):
                if i % 8 == 0:
                    i+=2
                    j+=1
                    del array[:]
                    array.append(line[0])
                    array.append(line[1])
                    array.append(line[2])

                elif (i+1) % 8 == 0:
                    array.append(line[i-3*j])
                    writer_out.writerow(array)

                else:
                    array.append(line[i-3*j])

                i+=1

        f_in.close()
        f_out.close()
```

The output is wrong and there is a space of 3 lines at the end of those lines whose length is 8. I suspect it might be the  writer_out.writerow(array) which is to blame.

Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, the logic you use ends up being fairly confusing. I'd do it more along these lines (this replaces your for loop), and this is more Pythonic:

```
for line in reader_in:
    header = line[:3]
    for i in xrange(3, len(line), 5):
        writer_out.writerow(header + line[i:i+5])
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. Thanks a ton! 
Could you point out where I was wrong (for learning purposes)?

Comment: Sure! Hmm I'm not sure exactly how to fix the logic so it works your way, but you definitely don't want to start a new line on `i%8==0`. You'd want to start a new line on `i` being 3, 8, 13, etc. - every 5 starting from 3. You'd need something mod 5. But in general your approach is very hard to keep track of because of all the index variables that you have to update. Better to do everything as in bulk as possible.